# All folders and files in SD card and USB drive appearing as locked!

Tags: 14.04, usb, sd-card

I am facing a wired problem and that is whenever I insert any **USB drive** or **SD card** in my computer, all folder and files inside it appear as **locked**! And therefore I **can't crate** any **new folder** and **delete** any **folder** from sd card or usb drive! I don't know why it is happening and how to solve this. Anybody please help me.

[image: Locked files and folders]

Answer (score 0):

Type in:

`sudo su`

enter your password.

Type in:

`chown <your_user_name> <disk_name>`

type:

`exit`

EDIT:

If your media is mounted read-only, it is probably needed to check group permissions:

First thing to do is to check the permissions on the hardware device mounting your card. You'll need to find the device name. To do this run the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Your device will probably be something along the lines of /dev/sdb1, it can be the SD Reader `/dev/mmcblk0p1`.

Next you need to get the permissions on this device:

`sudo ls -l /dev/mmcblk0p1`

Replace "/dev/mmcblk0p1" with your device location.

You need to be a member of group `disk` to be able to write to the SD card. You can check which groups your a member of with

`groups username`

so then:

`sudo usermod -G --append disk username`

This adds the group `disk` to your user's groups, which should allow you to now read & write to the SD card.